systemd service getting disabled - why?
I have a systemd service definition (see below) and I've enabled it but in some conditions the target python script starts and returns an error after 10-20 seconds. In this condition systemd loops restarting the service, which is what I want.
However after some time (to be determined) I find the service disabled, which I don't want to happen. How can I diagnose what is disabling the service, or what are likely causes and ways to prevent this?
[Unit]
Description=Glowflye Service
After=network.target
StartLimitIntervalSec=0
[Service]
WorkingDirectory=/root/glowflye
Type=simple
KillMode=mixed
Restart=always
RestartSec=1
User=root
ExecStart=/usr/bin/python3 -u /root/glowflye/glowflye.py

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target


When you say "disabled", do you mean "inactive"?  A unit will only become disabled if a disabling job was run, deleting the symbolic link inside of the unit that Wants= it as defined in the [Install] WantedBy= section.  An example is if someone ran systemctl disable glowflye.service.  If you really meant "inactive", then what is the output of systemctl status glowflye.service?  You can check the last few logs, and the exit status.

I do mean disabled, not inactive. It's as if someone ran 'systemctl disable glowflye.service' yet no one did.

This is too long for a comment, but probably not a full answer.
In the background, this unit is "enabled" if a symbolic link to your service exists in this location:
/etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/

If your unit becomes disabled, then it simply means that the symbolic link no longer exists.  There could be a few reasons for this:

Someone (or some script) ran systemctl disable glowflye.service
Someone (or some script) deleted this file
The directory with the multi-user.target.wants/ was unmounted or wiped.


I've seen people add systemctl disable to their ExecStop= or in bash scripts.  If you manage scripts around this service, check those.
You also see systemctl disable in prerm or postrm scripts.  These are run by the package manager when a package is upgraded.  It's not strange for a package upgrade to reload/restart a service, but that shouldn't disable a service.  It's also common for the same script to be run during uninstall, in which case you would expect a disable, but it should only be executed during uninstall (remove or purge).  I imagine your package could have a bug, where the service is erroneously disabled on upgrade.
If you're on a Debian-based distro, check /var/lib/dpkg/info/glowflye.{pre,post}rm and ensure that any disable or purge actions are protected in an if condition or case statement (though it's even better if the package maintainer uses debhelper to manage this).
case "$1" in
    purge|remove|abort-install)
        systemctl disable glowflye.service
    ;;
    upprade|failed-upgrade|abort-upgrade|disappear)
        # don't disable for these cases!
    ;;
esac


The links are usually in /etc/systemd/, but systemd can read configuration from lots of places (see man systemd.unit or a list of locations).  If these get created in a tmpfs location like /run/systemd/transient/*, then it'll be lost on reboot.  That's also true if /etc/systemd is a tmpfs mount.  Use systemctl enable and confirm via the stderr message that your link is created in /etc/systemd/system and then confirm via mount that this directory is actually on a persistent disk.

If you want to know the specific time at which the service was disabled, you could try an inotifywait:
$ inotifywait /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/glowflye.service && date

Then check journalctl for activity around that time.
